# SonarQube false positive SQL injection

Tags: java, jdbc, sonarqube, sql-injection

I have a query whose exact value depends on several input parameters. It looks a bit like this:

```
final String otherColumns = includeExtras ? ", baz" : "";
final String otherRestriction = name.equals("fred") ? " and bar = baz" : "";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "select foo, bar" + otherColumns + "from t where x = y" + otherRestriction);
```

SonarQube reports that this is vulnerable to SQL injection, but in fact it is obvious that all "injections" come from source code and not directly from parameters, therefore there is no vulnerability.

Is there a flag or setting to get SonarQube to spend more time doing data flow analysis so that it can see that there is no vulnerability here?

Comment: Have you tried refactoring the code so that you extract the query into a `final String` variable?

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection rule was raised because you don't use **Parameterized Query.**

[Here you can find more details about it.](https://jsparrow.github.io/rules/use-parameterized-query.html#description)

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work because if there are no other columns, `select foo, bar, from t` is not valid SQL syntax. Also, the parameter placeholder for otherRestriction makes the statement invalid. SQL parameterized statements can't use "?" just anywhere. They can only go in certain places, i.e. where a value would go. They can't be used to add keywords (which is what `otherRestrictions` contains).

Comment: hi @DodgyCodeException, thanks for the comment. You are right, my solution above is not completely right. In this case, the solution is using lots of if-else blocks. If you want, i can update the answer later today.

Comment: That's ok, I know what it will look like with lots of if-else blocks. My main query was whether SonarQube could be made to understand that there's no threat, so that I could avoid having lots of if-else blocks in my code. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Perfect, I will remove the code, so it does not confuse anybody.